# Dojo BorderContainer / ContentPane

Tags: html, django, dojo

I'm in traineeship in a company and I need to used the program of another trainee who programmed it in 2012. So I have done some update but I have a problem :

In the report of this trainee the web page was a column on the left with a "menu" for request, at the bottom a field for the result of request, and on all the remaining space a map with different information. For the moment the problem it's the map in region 'center' it's like in region 'top'.

Header :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojox/grid/resources/tundraGrid.css">

<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/2.11/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: false" ></script>

<script>
    require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dojo/_base/xhr", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojox/grid/DataGrid", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/data/ObjectStore", "dijit/form/Select", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/RadioButton", "dijit/ColorPalette", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/SimpleTextarea", "dijit/form/MultiSelect", "dijit/TooltipDialog", "dijit/form/DropDownButton", "dojox/gfx", "dijit/TitlePane", "dijit/form/NumberSpinner", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-dom"]);
</script>
<script src="/static/javascript/queries.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/javascript/map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/static/javascript/utils.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=KEY"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/home.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/map.css" />
```

Body :

```
<body class="soria" >
<div id="mainLayout" 
    data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer"
    data-dojo-props="design: 'sidebar'">

    <div id="mapLayout" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
         data-dojo-props="region: 'center', splitter: true"
         style="height:500px;">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="leftLayout"
        data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region: 'left', splitter: true, minSize: 330"
        style="min-width: 330px">
    <p>
        {% include "Home/forms/formQueries.html" %}
    </p>
    <p id="messageLimitNumberLines"  style="display: none">Le nombre de paramètres est limité à cinq. Vous ne pouvez pas en ajouter d'autres.</p>

    </div>

    <div id="datagridLayout" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" style="min-height: 300px" data-dojo-props="region: 'bottom', splitter: true, minSize: 300">
        <div id="datagrid" data-dojo-type="dojox/rid/DataGrid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**That is what I want**
[image: That is what I want]

**That is what I have**
[image: That is what I have]

I don't know if you need another code so tell me.

Comment: Hmm I couldn't understand the question at all. Could you please, post a mockup picture of what you expect?

Comment: what's the curren rendering ? could you give the issue picture

Comment: could you please create a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) with all your sources ( local js scripts )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a pane on the left, use 'leading' for the value of region

```
   <div id="leftLayout"
        data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
        data-dojo-props="region: 'leading', splitter: true, minSize: 330"
        style="min-width: 330px">
```

Then in the canter region you would place a separate border container there the map is in center region and datagrid layout in bottom region.

> **Regions**
>
> Each child element must have an attribute “region” which
> indicates where it should be positioned (most names are self
> explanatory):
>
> **top**
>
> **bottom**
>
> **right**
>
> **left**
>
> **center**
>
> **leading:** used have flexible layout in
> left-to-right/right-to-left environments. In ltr, it will be
> equivalent to left, in rtl equivalent to right.
>
> **trailing**: opposite of
> ‘leading’: right in ltr, left in rtl There can be multiple widgets for
> each region, in which case their order (i.e. closeness to the edge of
> the LayoutContainer) is controlled by their relative layoutPriority
> settings.
>
> There must always be one region marked ‘center’.

Source: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/LayoutContainer.html#dijit-layout-layoutcontainer